# How to fetch all messages between two users in ejabberd through REST API

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I'm currently working on integrating one to one chat in a web application using ejabberd.

I have tried to send message through `send_message` api to the **user1** from **user2**.

```
POST /api/send_message
{
  "type": "headline",
  "from": "user2@localhost",
  "to": "user1@localhost",
  "subject": "Testing",
  "body": "Sample message from user2"
}
```

When I opened `pidgin` I could see the message from `user2`. I received `0` as response which means success (as mentioned in the documentation).

Until I opened `pidgin` and see the message, The message has been treated as offline message. I could see that from the admin panel.

Now my question is How could I fetch all the messages between the `user1` and `user2` through a REST API endpoint?
Like how we use `send_message` endpoint to send message to an user from a different user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to view messages stored in offline (or in MAM archive).

Three possibilities:

- A) Use SQL storage for mod_offline (or mod_mam), then write a program that searches in your SQL database for the stored messages for account X.
- B) Write a small XMPP client that logins to the account and requests MAM archive of that account.
- C) Write a command in the ejabberd API to perform that task

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I tried the first option. so far, I could see the messages exchanged between the users in the **archives** table. But each message is stored two times (one for the sender and another one for the receiver).